# use mkdir on python and call list items

Tags: python, bash, mkdir, os.system

I would like to create new directories using the names of the subjects contained in the 'subjlist'. I call the bash function 'mkdir' for so, but the command '+subj+' seem not to recognize it as an item on the list. Do you know how to tackle this? Sorry for the silly question, I'm still crawling.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import os

path ='/data2/kizilirm/Mooney_fMRI_v01/subject_data'

subjlist = ['di21_1028', 'dn20_1072', 'ed17_1026', 'eo56_1016', 
'ge51_1039', 'ha96_1069', 'hp84_1024', 'ht02_1049', 'hw44_1051', 
'ij99_1073', 'ja58_1070', 'ju49_1036', 'km61_1064', 'kr25_1034', 
'lw37_1062', 'lz02_1041', 'mj45_1037', 'nm54_1017', 'od90_1040', 
'ol12_1063', 'os19_1038', 'ow93_1061', 'pk62_1074', 'qq31_1068',         
'qq39_1060', 'tt42_1025', 'ut93_1048', 'ws81_1042','xi27_1050', 
'zd63_1035']

#'series_2_t1_mpr_sag_1iso_p2', 
runlist = ['series_2_t1_mpr_sag_1iso_p2','series_3_BOLD-
fMRI_2x2x(3+0.3)_p2_run1', 'series_4_BOLD-fMRI_2x2x(3+0.3)_p2_run2', 
'series_5_BOLD-fMRI_2x2x(3+0.3)_p2_run3']

os.system("mkdir /home/mansur/Documents/mooney")
counter = 0

for subj in subjlist:
    for run in runlist:
        if run == 'series_2_t1_mpr_sag_1iso_p2':
            print subj , run
            counter = counter + 1
            os.system("mkdir -p 
'/home/mansur/Documents/mooney/'+subj+'/'anatomy/high_res") #Here is the problem!!!
        else:
            continue
print counter
```

Comment: you're passing the dir with + operators literally: `"mkdir -p '/home/mansur/Documents/mooney/'+subj+'/'anatomy/high_res"`

Comment: Why are you calling Bash `mkdir` instead of performing the system call via `os.mkdir` or `os.makedirs`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677066/python-os-system-issue-sh-1-command-not-found-command-works-interactivel

Comment: @PM2Ring, I'll try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
os.system("mkdir -p '/home/mansur/Documents/mooney/'+subj+'/'anatomy/high_res")
```

is passing `'/home/mansur/Documents/mooney/'+subj+'/'anatomy/high_res` to `mkdir` literally...

You would have to use `format`. Anyway, don't call a system command to perform `mkdir -p`. Compose your dir name using `os.path.join`, test if dir exists, and use `os.makedirs`

```
d = os.path.join("/home/mansur/Documents/mooney",subj,"anatomy/high_res")
if not os.path.exists(d):
    os.makedirs(d)
```

If something goes wrong, at least you get an exception. And it's way faster & portable.

Comment: Thanks, it worked really well! @Jean-Francois Fabre !